# Prestashop pretty url

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I'm having problems with prestashop 1.7 pretty urls. They're working for categories and products, but not for the rest of the site.

For example, if I go to "Shop Parameters" -> "SEO & URLS" and create a new one with "bestsales" from the pagename's dropdown and a Rewritten url of best-sales, the links pointing to that page don't change, they are like:

index.php?controller=best-sales

If I manually enter /best-sales, I got redirected to the non pretty url. I've already tried clearing the cache.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you try to do it in Incognito mode ? Maybe your web browser just cached the redirect. Chrome do that.

Comment: nop, same result. Tried with chrome and FF, both normal and incognito mode

Comment: Remove .htaccess and then regenerate it in backoffice maybe ?

Comment: I've tried to do that too. I get the same .htaccess with the same contents. Same result.

Comment: Did you check that url rewriting on your apache server is enabled ?

Comment: yes it is. Category and product pages are accesible via pretty urls with no problem at all. I've contacted the theme developer as I'm starting to think that is actually a problem with the theme I'm using.

Comment: i am using third party module after all efforts made mnually, https://addons.prestashop.com/en/url-redirects/31273-seo-friendly-urls.html